# Overlay text to a playing video

Tags: python, video

My project will play a video on a Pi with some buttons attached to the GPIO. What I need is to pop up a menu in response to those buttons, ideally without pausing the video if it's playing. I've seen two ways to play videos from python so far, pygame and omxplayer-wrapper (are there others more suited to this?).
The menu will be simple, things like vol up/down/mute, next/prev vid etc.

Anyone know of a text or menu overlay library to help with this please?